# JSON Array Syntax for PHP HTTP POST Requests

Tags: php, json, httpful

I'm attempting to write a PHP script that will query an API that I have access to. This API requires a JSON body post request, with one of the criteria being

```
"Analyses": ["Phenotype"]
```

Note that there are no double quotes around the second part of that string. When I try to pass this script below with Httpful, this script gives me an HTTP 500 result. Without the Analyses criteria, I get a proper response (albeit an error asking for the Analyses information) in a JSON format output. I assume this has something to do with the formatting/syntax of the Analyses string, and I'm not sure what to do about it. If I use single quotes, I get the 500 error. If I leave the quotes out entirely it assumes it's an array and give me an object error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I don't know how to pass that format without quotes around it.

```
$response = \Httpful\Request::post($url)
        ->sendsJson()
        ->body('{"apiUserKey":"abcde",
                "apiUserId":"efghi",
                "Species":"9606",
                "Analyses": "["Phenotype"]"
                 }')
        ->send();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Single quotes are not allowed in JSON. That error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is .net related? If they require an array, then `"Analyses": ["Phenotype", "B", "C"]` should be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're example is almost right, but you are including one set of double quotes to many. You are trying to pass an array of strings in the "Analysis" field. The array itself does not need to be in double quotes.

```
$response = \Httpful\Request::post($url)
    ->sendsJson()
    ->body('{"apiUserKey":"abcde",
            "apiUserId":"efghi",
            "Species":"9606",
            "Analyses": ["Phenotype"]
             }')
    ->send();
```

Comment: If I run the script you suggested, I got a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Robert above said that it may be a .net error? Usually that Analyses criteria will be an array of multiple (Ex. ["Phenotype", "Tissue"]). I did try json_encode(array...) and it returned a blank screen instead of a 500 error.

Comment: I'm afraid you are going to have to contact the developer of the remote service. As it is valid JSON for an array of strings.

Comment: I spoke with the developer and the error was actually coming not from the Analyses section, but rather mislabeling "Species" where it should have been "SpeciesID". Your formatting did solve the problem and will label this the correct answer. Thank you!